# LibUsb getting error timeout -7 on read transfer

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, usb, libusb, usb4java

I have been using the usb4java library and got to understand a lot of how a USB device communicates.

I'm using the usb4java low level API (LibUsb 1.0) library in my web application to read a barcode scanner input in Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi is updated to the latest packages through the [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) distribution.

I have the following examples of how to implement this process in Java from the below resources:

[Read data from an Adafruit Trinket over USB](https://gist.github.com/deckerego/a5e77dd01df00db92f21#file-readsensor-java)

[Usb4java examples](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/examples)

**Issue:**

I can successfully do:

- List all devices
- Choose my device according to the Vendor ID & Product ID
- Open device
- Detaching kernel driver
- Claiming the device

And when the time comes to read the device data that the scanner sent, I always get a timeout error (-7).

```
Opening device...
Claiming device...
Found Device, Data below
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Failure reading data -7
Releasing device interface...
Closing...
Exiting...
```

Example below, calling the method 10 times to get a response and with a 5 seconds timeout

```
for(int i=10; i >= 0; --i)
{
    writeOutput(read(DeviceHandle, this.bufferSize, this.timeout, this.transfer));
}
```

**Main class: missing defined variables, just to illustrate the process**

```
// Create the libusb context
Context context = new Context();

// Initialize the libusb context
int result = LibUsb.init(context);
if ((result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) || (result < 0))
{
    writeOutput("Unable to initialize libusb " + result);
}
else
{
    // Try to open the device.
    DeviceHandle DeviceHandle = new DeviceHandle();

    // Get device
    Device device = findDevice((short) 0x0c2e, (short) 0x0200);

    if (device == null)
    {
        writeConsole("Unable to find device");
    }
    else
    {
        writeConsole("Device found");
    }

    // Open I/O with the device handle
    result = LibUsb.open(device, DeviceHandle);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        writeOutput("Unable to open device");
        DeviceHandle = null;
    }
    else
    {
        writeOutput("Opening device");
        try
        {
            boolean detach = LibUsb.hasCapability(LibUsb.CAP_SUPPORTS_DETACH_KERNEL_DRIVER);
            int detachActive = LibUsb.kernelDriverActive(DeviceHandle, this.interFace);

            // Detach the kernel driver
            if ((detach) || (detachActive == 1))
            {
                result = LibUsb.detachKernelDriver(DeviceHandle, this.interFace);
                if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
                {
                    writeOutput("Cannot detach kernel from this interface (" + this.interFace + ") error " + result);

                }
                else
                {
                    writeOutput("Detaching kernel driver (" + this.interFace + ")");
                }
            }

            //set configuration
            result = LibUsb.setConfiguration(DeviceHandle, this.configuration);
            if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
            {
                writeOutput("Cannot set device configuration (" + this.configuration + ") error " + result);

            }
            else
            {
                writeOutput("Setting device configuration (" + this.configuration + ")");

                // Claim the device
                result = LibUsb.claimInterface(DeviceHandle, this.interFace);

                if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
                {
                    writeOutput("Cannot open device interface (" + this.interFace + ") error " + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writeOutput("Claiming device on interface (" + this.interFace + ")");

                        switch(this.transfer)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                writeOutput("Set to Interrupt Transfer type");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                writeOutput("Set to Bulk Transfer type");
                                break;
                        }

                        for (int i=10; i >= 0; --i)
                        {
                            writeOutput(read(DeviceHandle, this.bufferSize, this.timeout, this.transfer));
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        result = LibUsb.releaseInterface(DeviceHandle, this.interFace);
                        if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
                        {
                            writeOutput("Failure releasing device interface (" + this.interFace + ") error " + result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writeOutput("Releasing device interface (" + this.interFace + ")");
                        }

                        if ((detach) || (detachActive == 1))
                        {
                            result = LibUsb.attachKernelDriver(DeviceHandle, this.interFace);
                            if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
                            {
                                writeOutput("Cannot attach kernel driver back to the device (" + this.interFace + ") error " + result);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                writeOutput("Re attaching kernel driver back (" + this.interFace + ")");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            LibUsb.close(DeviceHandle);
            writeOutput("Closing... ");
        }
    }
    LibUsb.exit(context);
    writeOutput("Exiting... ");
}
```

** My method to get synchronous reads**

```
// Read data from device after claiming it
  public static String read(DeviceHandle handle, int size, long timeout, int readType) {

      byte endpointId = (byte) 0x81;
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      boolean started = false;

      while(true)
      {
          ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(size).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
          IntBuffer transferred = BufferUtils.allocateIntBuffer();

          int result;

          switch(readType)
          {
              case 0:
                  result = LibUsb.interruptTransfer(handle, endpointId, buffer, transferred, timeout);
                  break;

              case 1:
                  result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, endpointId, buffer, transferred, timeout);
                  break;

              default:
                  result = LibUsb.interruptTransfer(handle, endpointId, buffer, transferred, timeout);
                  break;
          }

          if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS)
          {
              return "Failure reading data with"
                          + " buffer size:"
                          + size + " bytes timeout:"
                          + timeout + " ms error code:"
                          + result;
          }
          else
          {
              CharBuffer charBuffer = buffer.asCharBuffer();
              while(charBuffer.hasRemaining())
              {
                  char nextChar = charBuffer.get();
                  if (nextChar == '\n')
                      started = true; //Start Character
                  else if(nextChar == '\r' && started)
                      return stringBuilder.toString(); //End Character
                  else if(started)
                      stringBuilder.append(nextChar);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

**This is the descriptor of the USB device**

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                 18
  bDescriptorType          1
  bcdUSB                1.10
  bDeviceClass             0 Per Interface
  bDeviceSubClass          0
  bDeviceProtocol          0
  bMaxPacketSize0          8
  idVendor            0x0c2e
  idProduct           0x0200
  bcdDevice            53.32
  iManufacturer            1 Metrologic
  iProduct                 2 Metrologic Scanner
  iSerial                  0
  bNumConfigurations       1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                  9
    bDescriptorType          2
    wTotalLength            34
    bNumInterfaces           1
    bConfigurationValue      1
    iConfiguration           3
    bmAttributes          0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    bMaxPower              300mA
    extralen                 0
    extra:

  Interface:
    numAltsetting          1
  Interface Descriptor:
    bLength                  9
    bDescriptorType          4
    bInterfaceNumber         0
    bAlternateSetting        0
    bNumEndpoints            1
    bInterfaceClass          3 HID
    bInterfaceSubClass       1
    bInterfaceProtocol       1
    iInterface               0
    extralen                 9
    extra:
      09 21 11 01 00 01 22 3f 00
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                  7
    bDescriptorType          5
    bEndpointAddress      0x81  EP 1 IN
    bmAttributes             3
      Transfer Type             Interrupt
      Synch Type                None
      Usage Type                Data
    wMaxPacketSize           8
    bInterval               10
    extralen                 0
    extra:
--- Device END ---
```

I'm using the Interface as 0, IN endpoint as 0x81, vendor ID as 0x0c2e, product ID as 0x0200. Also I have also changed the *LibUsb.bulkTransfer()* to *LibUsb.interruptTransfer()* as the device accepts only Interrupts transfers. The buffer is set to 8 bytes as the  *wMaxPacketSize* says.

I have tried and eliminate the below tests:

- Change the buffer transfer size from 1 ~ 64 Bytes
- Used LibUsb.bulkTransfer()
- Changed the timeout from 100 ~ 20000 milliseconds
- Added the LibUsb.clearhalt();

How do I overcome this issue? Did I miss something?

Comment: First off I can tell you you have to stick with interrupt Transfer and an 8 byte buffer, HID always works this way. Sometime you have to find the right interace for the endpoint. Have you tried claiming interface 1-5?

Comment: Besides: If you communicate directly with HID devices you don't get actual characters but HID data you have to interpret before you can read a string from it.

Comment: I knew that interfaces exists only from the LibUsb can "see". In the above list device only one exist, is that right? About the HID data you mean bytes in the buffer that I have allocated to. If you can see in the red() method there is a looping for processing the buffer.

Comment: Since I have one of those Metrologics around I tried it out myself and it worked (on Windows). The only difference there may be: Have you set any configuration? And with the buffer that is exactly the problem: One byte you receive of the device IS NOT a character. In this case all 8 bytes are only one key press and therefore one character max. ;)

Comment: So `wMaxPacketSize` is wrong? It says 8 Bytes for the whole transfer or for one character? Could you share your settings with me, maybe Im setting something wrong, i.e. endpoint,interface,buffer size,timeout, etc? How much bytes do I need to allocate before the interruptTransfer? I haven't seen any configuration set to any of the examples so I did not add one myself. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: No wMaxPacketSize is right. You have to read 8 bytes at a time. But those 8 bytes represent max one character. You have to transform them. In your case the interessting data is byte 0 and byte 2 all other bytes should be 0 any way. But I do not know exactly how this works and can not find any information directly. Try scanning test data and look what is coming out and reverse engineer your way.
What I use is configuration 1, interface 0, endpoint 0x81, buffersize 8 bytes, timeout 100ms.

Comment: Ok @dryman thank you very much. Will update you shortly.

Comment: I have added the method to set a configuration and still no luck. I have tested also a logitech keyboard and a mouse and always receiving timeout @dryman

Comment: Do you set configuration before or after claiming the interface? As far as I know it has to happen before. Can you maybe post the code you use before starting to read?

Comment: Before claiming the device. I confirm that everything works as should be and while the interrupt transfer happens I can use the scanner to scan a barcode and the output is not shown on the screen which means the device is claimed by my application. After the 10 attempts to get a read transfer the  application sets back the kernel and I can use the scanner with the Pi and output barcodes in a text file. Only that proof to me that everything works fine except the read transfer. Maybe its a bug in USB HID drivers of RaspBerry PI?

Comment: Maybe but it seems I'm at my wits' end. It all seems to work exept, that there is no data. I know this behaviour from Metrologic only if used with the COM usb interface but not with HID. But then the ProductID would be 0x07?0. In the case of COM you have to write once an transfer to endpoint 0x02 with content of one byte 0x80. It just seems, that HID doesn't even have a write endpoint to try it out.

Comment: Yes i know, I thought to use pi4j library for COM port. Yes only ENDPOINT IN possible for Metrologic. I have tested the code with a mouse too. Same error though. Do you know someone else that can help out to tag in? Thanks

Comment: Since the chat has been deleted it seems, I'm writing a comment here: Are you sure that the kernel driver is detached and not there anymore. Maybe try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558321/how-can-i-prevent-linux-from-initializing-a-usb-hid-device. And besides it may help to use a sniffer to get to know what goes wrong. (Sniff while normal driver is working and compare to the output your driver creates).